# class cannot be cast to class javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer error

Tags: java, swing, jtree

```
public class jtre extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static{
    
        try{
            
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NimbusLookAndFeel.class.getName());
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
            
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(jtre.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}}
   
    public jtre() {
        initComponents();
         jTree1.setCellRenderer(new WarnaRender());
        
        DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer)jTree1.getCellRenderer();
         Icon closedIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/ve.png");
         Icon openIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/veya.png");
         Icon leafIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/xor.png");
         renderer.setClosedIcon(closedIcon);
         renderer.setOpenIcon(openIcon);
         renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon);   }
 
public class WarnaRender implements TreeCellRenderer{

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText(value.toString());
        label.setOpaque(true);
        if(row %2 == 1){
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       } else {
        
        label.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        label.setForeground(Color.RED); } 
        return label;}}
```

I make a class which is called WarnaRender for coloring each node of jtree. My code is working. After that I want to add icons to jtree and I encountered an error which is "ClassCastException: class WarnaRender cannot be cast to class javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer (WarnaRender is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')". How can ı solve this problem? Can you help me. I investigated this error in the İnternet but I couldnt find the solution. Please help my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `WarnaRender` does not extends `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` so you can not cast it to this class.

So extend from it:

`public class WarnaRender extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {`

Comment: I tryed this code. It works but icons does not appear in the Jtree. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: You override `getTreeCellRendererComponent` which renders the icons

Comment: How can I Override it ? Can you write me please..

Comment: You have overridden it. What would you archive

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. I couldt override tghe code because ı dont know how to override this code. Can you write me how to override this code for solution of icons problem. The code works but jtree 's nodes doesnt apppear icons.I want the icons in Jtree to appear. Please help me help my code. How can appear the jtree 's icons ?Write the code please ...

Comment: You **have** overridden the code `@Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent`

Comment: Jens thanks for everthing. I looked my code and "@Override     public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent "  is already written in my code.                                             public class WarnaRender extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
 
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {      
my code is above the page. My code still doesn't show the icon.. How can ı show the icons .Please help me help my code.Thank you.

Comment: Don’t ask questions in the comment that are not related to the original question. Ask a new question for the new problem.